# Is it possible to avoid "The operation is insecure" when using Canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I have a HTML canvas (using KineticJS, however canvas aficionados should still chime in) that loads an image from another domain, places it onto the canvas and overlays some other information to product a final image. When I try to use canvas.toDataURL () to output the file, I receive the message "The operation is insecure.", obviously due to cross-domain restrictions.

I was wondering if anyone knows of any methods to work around this error (preferably cross-browser compatible). I was thinking a solution would be to copy the canvas to another canvas, kind of like a screenshot, but I can't find any method of doing so in the way that would avoid the error as I think it copies all canvas properties along with it.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Do you have the ability to use php?

Comment: No, this is entirely an Javascript based project.

Comment: If you use images from different domains the point of the [SOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) is that you cannot access the image data… What do you need `toDataURL` for, can you use a proxy on your domain for the images?

Comment: The code will later be used to power a browser extension, so I won't be able to use anything other than pure Javascript. I can't use any external software or languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the images are coming from a domain you don't control, then you're stuck with CORS limitations.

If you have access to configuring your own server, you can enable cross-origin sharing by setting this heading (read more about server security when doing this):

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: <origin> | *
```

Alternatively, if you host your images on a CORS enabled site like www.dropbox.com you can fetch images without the security errors like this:

```
var image1=new Image();
image1.onload=function(){
    context.drawImage(image1,0,0);
}
image1.crossOrigin="anonymous";
image1.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/99999999/yourCORSenabledPic.jpg";
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't control the domain that the images are coming from (I do have permission to use them though), so I guess I'm stuck with the limitations.

It's a bummer, but I understand why the restrictions are in place. I was just hoping someone might have come up with a workaround by now.

Comment: @Simon If you have access to install server-side programs with your server (PHP, .Net, CGI, Perl etc) then you can use your own server as a proxy. `http://myserver/getImage?http//:otherserver/img.png` basically streaming the image to your server instead and then to the client.

Comment: The problem is that it's going to be for an **extremely** high traffic website so I don't want to put any more load onto the server, nor do I want to setup another server just for this.

No big deal. I've learned that it still can't be done with Javascript, and I'm fine with that :)